# Return reference to template vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, reference

I start from simple class declaration where I defined inline template method which returning reference to specyfic type of container.

```
class JPetParamManager
{
public:
  enum ContainerType {kScintillator, kPM, kKB, kTRB, kTOMB};

  std::vector<JPetScin> fScintillators;
  std::vector<JPetPM>   fPMs;
  std::vector<JPetKB>   fKBs;
  std::vector<JPetTRB>  fTRBs;
  std::vector<JPetTOMB> fTOMBs;

  template <typename T>
  const std::vector<T>& getContainer(const JPetParamManager::ContainerType &p_containerType) const
  {
    switch(p_containerType) 
    {
    case kScintillator:
      return fScintillators;
    case kPM:
      return fPMs;
    case kKB:
      return fKBs;
    case kTRB:
      return fTRBs;
    case kTOMB:
      return fTOMBs;
    }
  }
}
```

In some another class method I want to return some container from class above:

```
void JPetAnalysisModuleKB::CreateOutputObjects(const char* outputFilename)
{
  std::vector<JPetKB> l_KBs22 = m_manager.getParamManagerInstance().getContainer<JPetKB>(JPetParamManager::ContainerType::kKB);
}
```

When I want to run this method in main I have error like:

```
./../../framework/JPetManager/../JPetParamManager/JPetParamManager.h: In member function ‘const std::vector<_RealType>& JPetParamManager::getContainer(const JPetParamManager::ContainerType&) const [with T = JPetKB]’:
JPetAnalysisModuleKB.cpp:55:126:   instantiated from here
./../../framework/JPetManager/../JPetParamManager/JPetParamManager.h:81:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::vector<JPetKB>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<JPetScin>’
./../../framework/JPetManager/../JPetParamManager/JPetParamManager.h:83:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::vector<JPetKB>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<JPetPM>’
./../../framework/JPetManager/../JPetParamManager/JPetParamManager.h:87:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::vector<JPetKB>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<JPetTRB>’
./../../framework/JPetManager/../JPetParamManager/JPetParamManager.h:89:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::vector<JPetKB>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<JPetTOMB>’
make: *** [JPetAnalysisModuleKB.o] Błąd 1
```

Comment: What the compiler says is that the return type (i.e., right hand side) doesn't match `std::vector<JPetKB> l_KBs22` (i.e., left hand side).

Comment: Just because you said `getContainer<JPetKB>(...)` doesn't mean the compiler can ignore the type mismatches in the remaining `case` statements!

Comment: Aren't the template parameter and the function parameter redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Introduction

Even though only one of your *switch-labels* will match and execute, the statement(s) associated with the others must still be valid.

The compiler is trying to tell you that not all of your returns can be used when returning a `std::vector<T> const&` (where `T` is the type passed to your function).

---

#### Explanation

The below instantiate `getContainer` in a way that makes it return a `std::vector<PetKB>`, but when instantiating the function the compiler will see that the *case-label* matched by *kScintillator* has a return of type `std::vector<JPetScin>`.

```
m_manager.getParamManagerInstance().getContainer<JPetKB> (JPetParamManager::kScintillator)
```

Since `std::vector<JPetScin>` cannot be converted to a `std::vector<PetKB>` the compiler complains and basically says that your code is ill-formed.

The same applies even if the *switch-condition* doesn't  select a *case* where the return-type is different; **all** paths must be able to return, otherwise an application is ill-formed.